# Распарсить строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Здравствуйте, можете помочь пожалуйста распарсить строку на js, строка имеет страшный вид, мне нужно порезать сперва её, а потом склеить в нужном порядке, закинуть в массив и сравнить с другими строками. Короче сильно сложно объяснил, давайте на примере. У меня есть строка:

> |file_0=enforcecopyinglibpackages.txt date_0=2011-09-23T02:20:42.000Z size_0=24 datefie_0=new/old|file_1=AutoVolumeControl.txt date_1=2011-09-07T22:02:06.000Z size_1=2 datefie_1=new/old|file_2=amp_gain.txt date_2=2011-09-07T22:02:06.000Z size_2=90 datefie_2=new/old|file_3=hosts date_3=2011-09-07T22:02:06.000Z size_3=25 datefie_3=new/old

Мне нужно привести её в такой вид:

```
var mas[0] = "file_0=enforcecopyinglibpackages.txt date_0=2011-09-23T02:20:42.000Z";
var mas[1] = "file_1=AutoVolumeControl.txt date_1=2011-09-07T22:02:06.000Z";
var mas[2] = "file_2=amp_gain.txt date_2=2011-09-07T22:02:06.000Z";
var mas[3] = "file_3=hosts date_3=2011-09-07T22:02:06.000Z";
```

А потом еще сравнить эти строки с другими строками по отдельности, примерно вот так:

```
 if(mas[0] == "AutoVolumeControl.txt" && mas[0] == "2011-09-23T02:20:42.000Z") {
         //do something
    //и так далее
}
```

Я понимаю что мне нужно регулярное выражение которые порежет и оставит только то что мне нужно, я такими навыками я не обладаю и прошу помощи у вас, как мне такое можно сделать?

**UPDATE:**
Ответ на вопрос: http://jsfiddle.net/dajver/qXrH7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mas = sss.split( '|file_' );
if( mas[0].indexOf('AutoVolumeControl.txt') != -1 && mas[0].indexOf('2011-09-23T02:20:42.000Z') != -1 )
{
 // OK
}
```

Comment: > Мне нужно привести её в такой вид:

как бэ там написано... ;)

Comment: А можете объяснить что делает .substr('AutoVolumeControl.txt') != -1 ? Я что то не пойму, оно как ни крути все равно возвращает все норм, хоть строка подходит хоть нет. http://jsfiddle.net/dajver/qXrH7/

Comment: если строка `AutoVolumeControl.txt` содержится в mas[0] b выполняется второе условие, то...

Comment: так оно выполняется в любом случае, даже если имя файла какое-то левое. Посмотрите пример пожалуйста который я выше запостил.

Comment: Sorry, стормозил, конечно же indexOf, а не substr :-)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вопрос решен! http://jsfiddle.net/dajver/qXrH7/1/ решение

Answer (score 1):

Используейте метод `split`

```
mystring.split("|");
```

в `mystring` содержится ваша строка